# What are the main issues you are likely to face when migrating from a bespoke system to JIRA?

Tags: import, migration, jira, bulk-load

It seems relatively straightforward from the documentation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/importing-data-from-csv-185729516.html)

1. Prepare SQL query to extract data to that format in CSV
2. Run Wizard
3. Profit

However there must be some gotchas and oversights that people have experienced when performing this migration or is it really as simple as the three steps described?

Comment: It depends how complicated the current system is. Do you have more types of incidents, more types of workflow, more products? What's your release process? We migrated custom system to JIRA in a corporate environment (hundreds of users and a big product) and it took 8 months together with custom plugin development.. so it depends.

Comment: Am now realising that the (our) corporate version of it appears to have a modified schema compared to what I was expecting in terms of mapping the fields from the old system